# Hibernate Validator does not check constraints of proxied subclass

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, proxy

I use Hibernate Validator and Hibernate ORM. Consider these three entities:

```
class Person {
   private Pet pet;

   @Valid
   public Pet getPet() {
     return pet;
   }
}

abstract class Pet {
   private String name;

   @NotNull
   @Size(min=1)
   public String getName() {
     return name;
   }
}

class Cat extends Pet {
  private String furColor;

  @NotNull(groups=Special.class)
  public String getFurColor() {
    return furColor;
  }
}
```

When I load an instance of class Person with Hibernate ORM which has a Cat as pet it happens that the association to 'pet' is lazy loaded and therefore is an HibernateProxy instance. However, the proxy does only extend from class Pet and not from the actual class Cat.

When the validator is applied to the instance of Person with groups Default and Special only the property 'name' of Pet is validated but the property 'furColor' is not validated:

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation
        .buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
validator.validate(person, Default.class, Special.class);
```

Is there a way, that the Validator will check all constraints of the delegating instance of a HibernateProxy instead of all constraints of the proxy itself?

I'm specifically asking to configuring/modifying the Validator to get the correct result. Changing Hibernate mappings to prevent ORM to create proxies is not possible in my case.

Comment: Can you post some code showing how you're invoking the validator?

Comment: I have added the invocation of the validator to the original question

Answer (score -1):

Annotations in javax.validation.constraints are not declared as @Inherited thus they will not be inherited in your case.

See - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html

You may create your own validation annotations that would be inherited.

Comment: The problem is not the inheritance of annotations but that the validator does not check constraints of proxied classes. @Inherited will not fix this.